A non-ordinary singularity "splitting" into another non-ordinary singularity on a curve
The classical book of Walker on algebraic curves described a method of computing the genus of curves with non-ordinary singularities by transforming such a curve into a birational one with only ordinary singularities. The result then follows from the degree-genus formula.
For positive integers $a > b \geq 2$, I have a curve
$$F: Y^a+Z^a-X^bZ^{a-b}=0,$$
written this way so that $P=[1:0:0]$ is the only singularity on $F$, which happens to be non-ordinary, of multiplicity $a-b$. Also, we check that the points $[0:1:0],[0:0:1]$ do not lie on $F$.
The plane $Z=0$ intersects $F$ at $P$ with multiplicity $a$, and thus we make the change of variables
$$X_0 = X, X_1=Y, X_2=Z-Y$$
to obtain the curve
$$F: X_1^a+(X_1+X_2)^a-X_0^b(X_1+X_2)^{a-b}.$$
One easily verifies that both $X_1=0,X_2=0$ now intersects $F$ at $P$ with multiplicty $a-b,$ which is what we want.
Now following the transformation of Walker, we have
$$G(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2) = F(Y_1Y_2,Y_0Y_2,Y_0Y_1).$$
This has a factor of $Y_0^{a-b}$, which, upon factoring, gives us
$$G(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2)=Y_0^{a-b}[Y_0^bY_2^a+Y_0^b(Y_1+Y_2)^a-(Y_1Y_2)^b(Y_1+Y_2)^{a-b}]  = Y_0^{a-b}H(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2).$$
The new curve $H$ has degree $a+b$ and is birational to $F$, and it has ordinary singular points $[1:0:0],[0:1:0],[0:0:1]$ of multiplicities $a,b,b$ respectively. The intersection of the plane $Y_0=0$ with $H$ will yield
$$(Y_1Y_2)^b(Y_1+Y_2)^{a-b} = 0,$$
which tells us that this plane is tangent to the singular point $Q=[0:1:-1]$ on $H$, and the multiplicity of the intersection is $a$ (with $a-b$ coming from the above equation, and $b$ coming from the multiplicity of $Q$ on $H$). By the method of Walker, it seems like the original non-ordinary singular point $P$ on $F$ only "splits" into this point, which is another non-ordinary singular point, and I am nowhere near performing any genus calculations.
Did I misunderstand something? How to I get around this phenomenon?

It is not clear what are you asking.

@Sasha Did the non-ordinary point really end up becoming another non-ordinary point, or were there mistakes in my steps? If it's the former, how can I compute the genus of the curve?

Maybe it is worth explaining what does "ordinary" and "non-ordinary" mean.

@Sasha I believe an ordinary singular point $P$ of multiplicity $m$ would have $m$ distinct tangents passing through it. Otherwise, then we would have tangent of higher multiplicities.

as walker says in theorem III.7.4, one obtains only ordinary singular points after a succession of such transformations, not just one.  so keep going.
